# R sprintf() adding thousand separator

Tags: r

How can `sprintf()` function be used to print thousand separators in R?
For example if:

```
x<-123456.98765
```

then if I want to print 0 decimal points after the whole number I use:

```
sprintf("%.0f", x)
```

and you will get: "123457"

But how to add with sprintif thousand separators and currency symbol at the end to get the following results:
123.457 $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2:** After OP clarification:

```
paste0(formatC(as.numeric(x), format="f", digits=0, big.mark=","), "$")
```

```
[1] "123,457$"
```

With `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%s $", format(x, big.mark=","))
[1] "123,457 $"
```

**Update 1:** Please see comment of jay.sf:

We could use `prettyNum`:

```
paste0(prettyNum(as.integer(x), big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE), ' $')
```

OR `dollar_format`:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/versions/0.4.1/topics/dollar_format

```
usd <- dollar_format(prefix = "", suffix = "$")
usd(x)

[1] "123,457$"
```

Comment: Tnx, but I need the answer for sprintf() function

Comment: I don't see sprintf() function anywhere

Comment: Please see my update!

Answer (score 1):

Use `format()` and `big.mark=","` instead

```
format(x, big.mark=",", nsmall=2)
```

Wrap that in a `paste()` to get the currency symbol too

```
paste0(format(x, big.mark=",", nsmall=2), "$")
```

To return

```
"123,456.99$"
```

If you must use `sprintf()` then

```
sprintf("%s$", format(x, big.mark=",", nsmall=2))
```